# Tables not showing within schemas following Table retrieval in QGIS (Oracle Spatial)

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

When connecting to an Oracle Spatial database, QGIS is not consistently populating the list of tables under each schema. When I try to expand a schema (as I have tried to do with PARKING in the picture below), nothing shows.

If I can expand a schema whilst the table retrieval is occurring then sometimes a list of tables will populate and I can access their contents but tables are missing from the list.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug report, not a question on GIS.SE

Comment: try through qgis desktop layer>add layer>add oracle spatial layer - seems okay through the application, but a bug in the browser as you have found,